# How to delete photos added in specific albums but not in others?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I wonder in swift and xcode: how do I delete photos added in specific albums but not in others. For example photos added in camera rolls but not in other albums? I know in principle, apple make it only a reference link of the same photo in camera rolls in other album, so if delete in one, you will delete in all others. But would it be possible to make any way around it? For example copy it as a file copy to new album with different names? 
Any one have any idea how to work around with it ?

Thank you,

Comment: Can you be more specific about your question? Are you trying to build a photo viewer app? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "delete command"? And how is this related to cocos2d-iphone?

Comment: I want to know how is it possible to delete a photo but not deleting it from other albums.

Comment: You might want to change your question, then, as it's not really clear from it what you are trying to accomplish, not why xcode or cocos2d-iphone are related. You'll get more chances of someone answering it if it's more clear: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Photos` framework to remove the photo from the specific album. You need to `PHAssetCollection` object (say `album`) of that album and `PHAsset` of the photo (say `asset`) which belongs to that album.

In order to remove the asset from the particular album, you need to create `PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest` object (say `request`) with that `album` and then delete the `asset` with the help of `request` using method `removeAssets`.

**Sample**

```
let album : PHAssetCollection = /*Your album object*/
let asset : PHAsset = /*Your Asset belongs to album*/
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        guard let request = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: album) else {
            return
        }
        request.removeAssets([asset] as NSArray)
    }) { (result, error) in
        print("completionBlock",result, error)
    }
```

Comment: but will that delete the same photo in different albums ? since there is only one record of that photo but it is created only a "path" or link in different album to refer to. So basically if you delete from anywhere it will delete that only one record and all the other place refer to it will not be able to access. Am I understanding right ?

Comment: If you are removing photo with `PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: )`. It will simply modify an asset collection’s metadata or when adding or removing assets without regard to their arrangement. Therefore if assets being used in different places it will not remove the asset permanently from the storage.

Comment: then how do I check if a photo is already referred to in another album ? Meaning if I add a photo in camera album to another album, how could I check that in the code ?

Comment: you have any comment for my above query?

Comment: There is no instance method in `PHAsset` class to identify whether the assets belong to more album or not, you have to write your own method to check in all another album for the same asset.

Comment: can you give a little example of how to write it? Thank you!

Comment: In order to delete a asset (PHAsset) from a specific album need to use PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets([asset] as NSArray) instead of PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: ) for more take a review of apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetchangerequest/1624062-deleteassets

Answer (score 0):

You can filter selected album and delete album like below

```
  if let assetCollection = album.filter({$0 == selectedAlbum}).first?.collection{
     PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
       PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.deleteAssetCollections([assetCollection] as NSArray)
        }, completionHandler: { (success, error) in
            if success {
               //enter code here
               Print("Successfully Deleted")
             }
            else if error = error {
              //enter error handler code here
              print(error)
             }
         }
```